# NSMutableURLRequest for JSON data against key in form

Tags: ios, json, rest, nsurlrequest, nsmutableurlrequest

I need to send JSON data in form against a key say `data`. But I can't find any option to set key in `setHTTPBody`. Following is the code I am using:

```
responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSString *JSONStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:JSONData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"JSON string: %@", JSONStr);
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress]];

    if (isPost) {
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setHTTPBody:JSONData];
    }
    NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [urlConnection start];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) you can send JSON data very easily:

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];


NSDictionary *params = @ {@"user" :txtUserName, @"pwd" :txtPwd };


[manager POST:URL parameters:params
success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
}
failure:
 ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
 }];
```

Comment: I already can send JSON using NSMutableURLRequest. But all I want is that I need to send JSON against a key and in "form" section of REST Body.